# Pandas pull rows where any column contains certain strings

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, null

I'm trying to return rows where any of my columns contain any of the words in a word list. Let's say `word_list = ['Synthetic', 'Advanced or Advantage/Excellence']`. I've tried the following code `df[df.apply(' '.join, 1).str.contains('|'.join(word_list))]`.

The problem is some of my columns contain null values, so after running that code I got the error `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found` (maybe Pandas treats the null values as "int" type?)

Is there anyway I can construct my code in a way that Pandas can either ignore the null values, or treat the null values as string, so that my function can work?

Comment: Can you provide an example of your data?

Comment: filter out rows with null values first with `df.dropna(inplace=True)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to concatenate an `int` and a `str`, you can try this instead:

```
df[df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.contains('|'.join(word_list), case=False).any(), axis=1)]
```

I've tried this with int/float/NaNs in the columns and worked ok for me.