# Pandas: select rows where any column passes condition

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

## How can I return all rows where one of the columns passes a given condition, WITHOUT specifying any column?

My situation is as follows:

```py
import pandas as pd
print(pd.__version__) # 1.5.2

x = [ 1, 2, 3 ]
y = [ 4, 5, 6 ]
z = [ 7, 8, 9 ]

df = pd.DataFrame({
  "a": x,
  "b": y,
  "c": z
})
```

I know you can apply a condition on a given column in order to return all the rows where that column passes the condition.

```py
df.loc[df.a > 1]
# or
df.loc[df["a"] > 1]
```

Which would output:

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 5 | 8 |
| 3 | 6 | 9 |

---

I want to select all rows from the data frame, where any of the columns passes the given condition.

```
df.loc["*" > 1]
```

Which should output:

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 7 |
| 2 | 5 | 8 |
| 3 | 6 | 9 |

I have tried the following but it sets any non matching values to NaN:

```
df[df > 1]
```

Output:

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NaN | 4 | 7 |
| 2 | 5 | 8 |
| 3 | 6 | 9 |

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use vectorial code with [`any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) and [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df[df.gt(1).any(axis=1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

The following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75424185/pandas-pull-rows-where-any-column-contains-certain-strings#answer-75424280) provided the answer:

```py
df[df.apply(lambda row: row.ge(1).any(), axis=1)]
```

Comment: don't use `apply` for such a task, this is a waste of pandas capabilities ;)

Answer (score 1):

you use this:

```
df[(df > 1).any(axis=1)]
```